# Syntax highlighting for Crystal

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

[Crystal](http://crystal-lang.org) is a new programming language with Ruby inspired syntax. So until it's popular enough for a plugin for Google code prettify, I propose to associate the [crystal-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crystal-lang) tag with `lang-rb`, which should work well enough for the time being.

Comment: Until implemented users can use `<-- language: lang-rb -->` to get the pretifier choose that highlighting

Comment: @rene it appears that the OP going through and editing the language tag into posts is what's inspired this post ;)

Comment: Oh, is that a desired side-effect or do you hate me now @JonClements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at the 7 questions tagged - and the project statement of *Have the same syntax as Ruby, or at least as similar as possible.* - I can't see any negative consequencing implementing this (for now), especially if all people active in the tag are going to edit in/manually specify lang highlighting anyway.

If the tag increases in popularity or there comes a more specific Crystal code prettify, it can be switched to that later (and not require people to then edit out the manually introduced ruby lang statements).